# Magento 2 : How to get Category From CategoryFactory without Using Load() Function in Loop

Tags: magento-2.1, category, collection, category-products

I want to load all category from CategoryFactory and I'm using for loop to do that, but it's not good to load category in loop. Is there any another ways to get category from CategoryFactory.
Here is my function:

```
foreach ($this->categoryCollection->create() as $category) {
            //Load category instance
            $categoryId = $category->getData('entity_id');
            $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $categoryData = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
    //do somthing here..
}
```

Comment: can you specify what you want from specific category?

Comment: can u please why you load full category model `$categoryData = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);`

Comment: you can not load a single category without load() but you can have whole collection without load()

Comment: I just want to get some specific attribute for each category. So Amit Bera's answer is what i'm looking for. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using ***category collection  class*** for getting the category collection `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory`

Then i don't thought that you ***need to use direct  object manage*** `$_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')` of category model  for getting **category object** **using load()**.

***In side of a loop,use direct object manager for load a full model is really bad idea.***

I assume, if you may be ***using load() function inside of loop for getting a particular*** of getting a ***particular category attribute field value***.

In this case, you should add `addAttributeToSelect('ATTRIBUTE_CODE')` at your collection.

```
$collection = $this->categoryCollection->create();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
/**
* Use addAttributeToSelect('*') for all fields value
*/

foreach ($collection as $category) {
            //Load category instance
            $categoryId = $category->getData('entity_id');
            $categoryId = $category->getData('ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

}
```

Comment: oh Thank you. It is exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome...